# Removing try/catch exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, sudoku

I'm working on a sudoku solver and the solve-method gives an error which I've temporarily "solved" with a try and catch exception.

However, I'm a little concerned that I'm blanket catching an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I simply want to fix the error instead of hiding it in a try/catch exception.

This is what the try/catch looks like:

```
    try {
        if (puzzle.getNum(i, j) != puzzle.blank)
            return solve(nexti, nextj);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return true;
    }
```

I'm thinking that since I already got the information when `x > 8` it is time to change row, which leads to `y++`. And when `y > 8`, the program should be done since all 81 (9x9) cells has been filled.

I'm thinking around the lines of changing the try/catch method for a simple

```
if((i > 8) && (j > 8)){
        return true;
}
```

but that gives me a bunch of errors as well.

I'm sure the fix is very simple but conceptually important.

Comment: what is throwing the out of bounds exception (i don't see any array access going on)?

Comment: Could it be possible to make it work by changing the `if` condition you proposed, using || instead &&?

Answer (score 1):

I would add this check at the beginning of the method:

```
if( i >= puzzle.puzzleSize || j >= puzzle.puzzleSize )
{
    return false;
}
```

If you're out of bounds of the puzzle board in either direction, you clearly haven't found a solution, thus you return false.  Your computation of nexti and nextj can be after this check because the next recursive call would handle the case when they become out of bounds.

You might be tempted to say "well, my nextj calcuation uses modulus, so it will never be out of bounds."  That's true, but you also can't guarantee the method will be called with the right parameters, so it's worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using recursive method, you should have as first line of code the "ending condition".

Adding

```
if((i > 8) && (j > 8)){
      return true;
}
```

At the beginning of your method should do the trick (If you are sure that you never send i=9 when j < 8). What are the other errors you got when doing this ?